# Llamada de métodos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Tengo dos scripts en Python pero ahora quiero hacer uno solo, terminando de llamar un método luego quiero llamar el otro pero me dice

> name 'readImage' is not defined

Asi es como estoy llamando los métodos:

```
def decoder(image):
    #code
    
def main():
    #code
    decoder(frame)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()#se ejecuta correctamente
    readImage(frame)#esta me da el error anterior
    
def readImage(img):
    #code
```

El último método `readImage()` es de otro script y lo quiero unificar con lo que ya esta ahí en el primer script.

Aclarando es la primera vez que estoy usando Python, quizás sea algo sencillo para alguien con algo de experiencia en este lenguaje, igual sigo buscando información en San Google :)

Comment: el `if` debería ir al final de todo, después de todas las definiciones de funciones. Python es interpretado, por lo que si haces referencia a una función o variable que se define después de donde se usa te dará un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifica el orden de tus funciones:

```
def decoder(image):
    #code
    
def main():
    #code
    decoder(frame)

def readImage(img):
    #code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() #se ejecuta correctamente
    readImage(frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

**La definición de una función debe estar por encima de su llamada**. Debes modificar el orden del código y eso solucionará el problema.